# How to change the manufacturer property in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

*I already asked this question [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59822038/807307), but it is not getting attention; maybe here is a better place*

I am running the Android emulator that comes with the Android Studio software. I created an AVD based on Pixel 2. Opening the ADB shell I get:

```
$ getprop ro.product.manufacturer
unknown
```

I would like to change the string returned as property `ro.product.manufacturer`, because I have an app the refuses to run on an "unknown" device. How can I do that?

The file `config.ini` for the AVD has a line

```
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
```

but this does not seem to be the same thing.

Comment: I've just used google and found [this](http://ronald-stevanus.blogspot.com/2013/10/change-manufacturer-and-brand-of.html). Have no idea does it work but it seems pretty easy to check.

Comment: Yes, it works! Even better than that link, because nowadays it seems that the filesystem is ext4 instead of YAFFS, so you just loop-mount it, modify the file and go.

Comment: Google always helps :D